# Exercise 7.6 of the texbook

Tags: tex-core, csname

Exercise 7.6 of the texbook is as follows:

> What tokens does '`\expandafter\string\csname a\string\   b\endcsname`' produce? (There are three spaces before the `b`.)

Here is my analysis to this problem and I'd like to know whether it's correct.

First of all, `a\string\   b` produces a token list: `a`(catcode 11), `\`(catcode 12), `space`(catcode 12) and `b`(catcode 11).

Then `\csname` and `\endcsname` make the token list into a control sequence `\a\ b`.

Finally, `\string` makes the control sequence into a list of character tokens: `\`(catcode 12), `a`(catcode 12), `\`(catcode 12), `space`(catcode 10), `b`(catcode 12)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is in the back of the book

Your answer is right but mid stage analysis is wrong, `\string\`  makes a catcode 12 `\` and catcode 10 space.

Also your implied timing is a bit misleading, The `\csname` is expanded first, before the inner `\string`, but then tokens are just collected up and made into a control sequence when `\endcsame` is reached.